# Response.Filter making multiple calls to Write()?

Tags: httpresponse, response.filter

For some time I am using custom Response.Filter for rewrite purposes. Since I never tested this module, I decided to run a few tests and spotted something I did not expect.

I realized that pages are written to stream using multiple calls to Write().

So does it mean that my rewrite logic is being called multiple times for the same chunk of html or html is actually divided in partitions?

Please help me understand how Write() works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pages are written in chunks.

Each chunk is sent trhough your filter exactly once.